# Equivalence of weak and strong continuity for finite discrete spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, continuity, weak-topology

Consider finite discrete sets $X$ and $A$ and a kernel $c:X\times A\to X$. As $X$ and $A$ are discrete sets endowed with discrete topology, we know that the function $c$ is continuous (in the strong sense).

Consider the following definition of weak continuity: a kernel $c$ is weakly continuous if the map
$(x,a)\to\int_X f(z)c(dz|x,a)$
is continuous for all $f\in C_b(X)$.

We know that if $c$ is linear there exists an equivalence between weak and 'strong' continuity. However, $c$ might not be linear in this case.

As we are working on finite discrete sets, can we derive the following implication: $c$ continuous implies that $c$ weakly continuous ? If not, is there any condition for such results ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Every function on a finite set is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that every function on a finite set is continuous in the strong sense. My question is more related to the fact whether this strong continuity implies any result on weak continuity.

Comment: Strong continuity always implies weak continuity. Here, the other direction works too.

Comment: I know the equivalence result between 'strong' and weak continuity for linear function. However, is it true for non-linear function?

Comment: For functions into the space of probability distributions on a finite set, it doesn't matter whether the latter space is endowed with the weak or strong topology. But for functions on a finite set (or any discrete topological space for the matter), even more is true: They are continuous, irrespective of the codomain.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.